# Can I tune kernel parameters inside KVM box?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

Some packages (like Postgree) require to tune kernel parameters for better performance.

For this reason I definitely can't use containers (like Docker/CoreOS).

But what about KVM? Should I rent bare metal or it is possible to tune kernel parameters inside KVM box?

Consider KVM hosting offers much cheaper than bare metal servers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tune kernel parameters inside KVM. You can't tune KVM host kernel parameters.

It is possible to tune kernel parameters inside containers. Not all, but many.

If you have a specific workload that requires kernel tuning, it may be best to run it on baremetal with properly selected hardware components for the load type.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, when you boot your own kernel, nearly any kernel parameter can be tuned. Any VM with virtual hardware. It doesn't really matter which hypervisor, KVM, Hyper-V, VMware, Xen.

Consider (large) VMs as an alternative to "bare metal". Several clouds offer very large instance sizes.